# Inverted faces in surface mesh produced by Polygonal Surface Reconstruction

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to use Polygonal Surface Reconstruction with building point cloud to create simplified building models.
I did first tests with [this CGAL code example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygonal_surface_reconstruction/Polygonal_surface_reconstruction_2polyfit_example_without_input_planes_8cpp-example.html) and got first promising results.
As an example, I used [this point cloud](https://drive.protonmail.com/urls/V3JF4CFNPW#6yW5Y1f0YUpu) with vertex normals correctly oriented and got [the following result](https://drive.protonmail.com/urls/26QYCE5VNM#cACyIl5FBLJP) from PSR. Some faces are clearly inverted (dark faces with normals pointing inside the watertight mesh and therefore not visible).
[image]

I was wondering if there a way to fix this face orientation error. I've noticed orientation methods on Polygon mesh but I don't really know to apply them to the resulting PSR surface mesh. As far as logic is concerned making normal point outwards should not be too complicated I guess.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [reverse_face_orientations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#gad8a3439883e3e76651f96d15ba58b2bc) in the [Polygon mesh processing](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html) package.

Note that this package has several functions that can help you to correct/modify your mesh.

Comment: Thanks ! I've made some small progress in understanding the different data structures ;) In PMP there are functions that work on triangle mesh or polygon mesh and I can go from my surface_mesh to a triangle mesh by using `PMP::triangulate_faces()`. `reverse_face_orientations` seems to reverse all faces and in my case I've got some faces that are correct and some that aren't. I've tried other PMP orientation methods but I'm still struggling. Basically I'm looking for something like the python`trimesh.repair.fix_normals` method that would fix winding and normals for a watertight mesh.

Comment: You can use the function [orient_to_bound_a_volume()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#gafdbc256d06536f6aca2558bc1a0156e2)

Comment: @sloriot Thanks for your comment. I had to deal with other priorities since february. Back to CGAL now :) I noticed that CGAL::is_closed() was not true for the Surface_Mesh produced by polyfit in this case. I finally resorted to polygon_mesh_to_polygon_soup() => repair_polygon_soup()  => orient_polygon_soup() => polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh(). It seems to be working fine on the first few building I tested. Do you think a surface_mesh validation of some sort should be included in CGAL polyfit ? Should I create an issue in https://github.com/CGAL/cgal ?

Comment: Yes I think it would make sense so that the author can have a look.